# How to add NSURL session progress to table view cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Calculus Video app I created based on tableviews and I am trying to add the functionality for offline saving of video files. I understand what I am trying to achieve but I am getting stumped by adding the progress bar to the specific cells:

Currently, the download is started by clicking on the accessory button. I have the following method

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //Code to save Video to Documents directory goes here

        let currentVideo = videos[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        guard currentVideo.saved == false else {
            print("Video is already saved")
            return
        }

        guard let url = currentVideo.url else {
            print("Video not found...url is invalid")
            return
        }

        guard currentVideo.downloading == false else {
            print("Video is already downloading")
            return
        }

        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
            delegate: self,
            delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

        let downloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(url)
        downloadTask.resume()
}
```

Now, I am implementing the NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate methods, of which the relevant one is below

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    print(progress) //this works and shows progress
}
```

Now, all I want to do is to update the property

```
currentVideo.progress = progress  

//where currentVideo is the video for the cell that was tapped
```

The problem is I do not know how to get the current video inside of this delegate method. I was trying to somehow figure out how to use the downloadTask.taskIdentifier or something like that but I am not able to figure it out. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: save your download task session.hashValue along with your task identifier

Comment: change currentVideo.downloading == false to !currentVideo.downloading

Comment: I like currentVideo.downloading == false because it is more descriptive.

Comment: you should avoid comparing a Bool object to true or false

Comment: the task identifier may not be unique thats why you need to save your session hash value. You can also check downloadTask.response?.URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it following way.

1. Declare global variable under your class

   ```
   var selectedIndex:NSIndexPath!
   ```
2. Then in `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` method

   ```
   selectedIndex = indexPath
   ```
3. Now, in delegate method `downloadTask` assign value

   ```
   let currentVideo = videos[selectedIndex.section][selectedIndex.row]
   currentVideo = // Your value
   ```

Comment: Hmm, this looks like it would work. I will try it and see how it goes.

Comment: This worked but now I have a separate problem. This does not work well when I try to download multiple files at once. It seems to get a bit confused at that point. I also am not sure, if multiple files are downloading at once, how do I know which file has downloaded so I can get its title. I will probably have to post a separate question.